# ASP.NET Core Razor Page Pass ID to Modal

Tags: asp.net

I have been using Modals in Razor Pages and passing data using values in the page model (@Model.Id). Unfortunatly, I now need to pass an id which is selected from the page (data-buttonno).

```
<button type="button" data-target="#process" data-toggle="modal" data-buttonno="one">
        <span class="text">Button 1</span>
</button>


<button type="button" data-target="#process" data-toggle="modal" data-buttonno="two">
        <span class="text">Button 2</span>
</button>


<button type="button" data-target="#process" data-toggle="modal" data-buttonno="three">
        <span class="text">Button 3</span>
</button>
```

I want to set buttonno as a hidden field in the modal to pass back to my cs, but I cant work out how?

```
<div id="process" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">

    <form asp-page-handler="assignTask" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Id" />
        <input type="hidden" name="buttonNo" value=??/>
        <div class="form-group">
             <button class="btn btn-success btn-icon-split">
                <span class="text">Submit</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

page.cs

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAssignAsync(int id, int buttonNo)
        {
        }
```

Comment: You don't use server side code, you need to use javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a client side language, or a javascript dependent library like JQuery.

```
<button class="js-modal-update" type="button" data-target="#process" data-toggle="modal" data-buttonno="one">
    <span class="text">Button 1</span>
</button>
<button class="js-modal-update" type="button" data-target="#process" data-toggle="modal" data-buttonno="two">
    <span class="text">Button 2</span>
</button>
<button class="js-modal-update" type="button" data-target="#process" data-toggle="modal" data-buttonno="three">
    <span class="text">Button 3</span>
</button>
```

I've given your buttons a class attribute so we can target them on the server side.

```
//add this to your js file after jquery library
$(function(){
    //loop through your buttons and add a click event
    $('.js-modal-update').on('click', function(){
        //get the button number of the control
        const buttonNumber = $(this).attr('data-buttonno');
        //get the input from the modal
        let inputField = $('#process').find('input[type="hidden"][name="buttonNo"]');
        //assign the value
        $(inputField).val(buttonNumber);
    });
});
```